# Probability to pick couples of numbers from a set of the first $n$ natural numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am stuck on the following problem: I have a set $A$ of the first $n$ natural numbers. I define a new set $B$ picking randomly $m$ numbers from $A$. What is the probability to have at least $k$ couples of consecutive numbers in $B$? For example, I put $n=100$, $m=5$, $k=2$. So I have:
$$A=\{j=1,2,3,...,n\}$$
What is the probability that in the set 
$$B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5\}$$ I have $2$ couples of consecutive numbers?
For instance, the set $$B=\{5,6,34,12,13\}$$ contains two valid couples.
The set:
$$B=\{90,20,12,13,66\}$$ doesn't qualify as a success.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want the probability of _exactly_ $k$ couples in $B$, or _at least_ $k$? How do you deal with a situation like $B=\{12,13,14, 20, 25\}$? Does that count as two couples?

Comment: @kccu: at least $k$ couples. In your example: $\{B=12,13,14,20,25\}$ is good because it contains $3$ couples

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: I get the reason for $\{12,13,14,20,25\}$ counting as two couples, but why *three*?

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra By $n$ couples, do you mean there are $n$ consecutive numbers?

Comment: @DylanSp: $k$ couples means $k$ couples of consecutive numbers $\{j,j+1\}$

Comment: I predict no (complete) answers to this question. See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915400/how-many-subsets-does-the-set-1-2-dots-n-have-that-contain-no-two-con  for a far simpler special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an easy way.  For your example, there are ${100 \choose 5} = 75287520$ possibilities for $B$.  Of those, ${96 \choose 5}=61124064$ have no neighboring pairs.  To count the number with neighboring pairs, you have $2$ choices pair at the end, then ${95 \choose 3}=138415$ ways to choose three non-neighbors out of what is rest, plus $97$ ways to choose a central pair and ${94 \choose 3}=134044$.  The ways to choose $B$ without two pairs is then $61124064+2*138415+97*134044=74403162$  The chance of two pairs is then $1-74403162/75287520\approx 0.01175$