# How many subsets are there of set $[2n]$ (for $n > 0$) where no two chosen numbers differ by exactly $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

How many subsets are there of set $[2n]$ (for $n > 0$) where no two chosen numbers differ by exactly $n$?

I know that for consecutive numbers the answer would obey Fibonacci-like formula ([How many subsets does the set $\{1, 2, \dots , n\}$ have that contain no two consecutive integers if $1$ and $n$ also count as consecutive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915400/how-many-subsets-does-the-set-1-2-dots-n-have-that-contain-no-two-con?rq=1)).

But is there any way to translate that into the case with $2n$ numbers without elements differing by $n$?

Comment: So, from each pair $\{a,a+n\}$ you pick at most one element to be in your subset. It should fall out pretty quickly from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following pairs in your set:
$$(1,n+1), (2,n+2),\ldots, (n, 2n).$$ From each pair, you can choose one element, the other element, or neither. So you have $3^n$ total subsets.

Comment: Thus depriving OP of the pleasures of figuring it out from my comment.